# Sound off after some time in Alarm manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeat

I have a mechanism that when the alarms rings the media player is ringing the tune. It works perfectly when alarm sets. But when i reboot the device then the media player voice stops after some time. i had checked this question but not get any suitable answer.
[android alarm manager sound after reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454251/android-alarm-manager-sound-after-reboot)
it has same problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you scheduled alarm still to work after reboot you need to register BroadcastRecevier where to do some actions after reboot intent was sent. For example check if set previously alarm is still exist or schedule new one. 
BroadcastRecevier in manifest with :

```
   <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

and permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```